# How to get specific type from union type by key field

Tags: typescript

I'd like to get subtype from a union type via key field. Is it possible?

```
type T1 = {type: 'a', a1: string, a2: boolean}
type T2 = {type: 'b', b1: string}
type T3 = {type: 'c', c1: number}
// ...

type UnionT = T1 | T2 | T3 // ...

type SomeCoolType<T extends {type: string}, S extends T["type"]> = T // ... is it possible?

type SomeCoolType<UT, 'a'> // === {type: 'a', a1: string, a2: boolean}
type SomeCoolType<UT, 'b'> // === {type: 'b', b1: string}
// ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a built-in [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility type, that allows to retrieve members of a union if they extend the second argument:

```
type SomeCoolType<T extends { type: string }, S extends T['type']> = Extract<T, { type: S }>;
```

Usage:

```
type Case1 = SomeCoolType<UnionT, 'a'>; // === {type: 'a', a1: string, a2: boolean}
type Case2 = SomeCoolType<UnionT, 'b'>; // === {type: 'b', b1: string}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3lUkBcUDkBDHAbijzmwGdgAnASwDsBzYvAJmwCMB7TgGwjzpQAvoQBQGaDBZJU6cBGw52RKOzJRKtRsLETYAZhloJigMYrT6ugFcAtuwhUdogPQuoAOi+jx8qAFU6Gk46GBl4KAAfWGlomH1iN09vX0goAGVOWwgAYW4eGHkAHjCIAA9gCDoAE3JZEw1qegZhABoMqHLKmrqYAG0cCRwAXQA+GQBRCqo8U2AS9uN5bHThUbFU6By8cggEZEzsvN5CyCLA4ND2-Bx1qCTER9QGm-bSCibGN7ZVfP46ISbKDbXbSA5ZXL5U4Qc5BEIwa7KO4PJ4oF7KdpqD5aBiAoA)